# Typos at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product (?) and tensor product over a ring!

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am looking at a Wikipedia article on “tensor product” with URL as follows. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product?

The article is good, however, seems to me there are more than one typos that might confuse beginners.
(1) Given a vector $\mathbf {v} ={\begin{bmatrix}v_{1}\\v_{2}\\\cdots \\v_{m}\end{bmatrix}}$ and
$\mathbf {w} ={\begin{bmatrix}w_{1}\\w_{2}\\\cdots \\w_{n}\end{bmatrix}}$, their outer product should have been ${ \mathbf {v} \otimes \mathbf {w} ={\begin{bmatrix}v_{1}w_{1}&v_{1}w_{2}&\cdots &v_{1}w_{n}\\v_{2}w_{1}&v_{2}w_{2}&\cdots &v_{2}w_{n}\\\cdots \\v_{m}w_{1}&v_{m}w_{2}&\cdots &v_{m}w_{n}\end{bmatrix}}}$. The original one at Wikipedia looks a typo on the subscripts.

(2) The formula on the ratios of vector components, I wonder, should have been
$${\frac {v_{j}}{v_{i}}}={\frac {v_{j}w_{k}}{v_{i}w_{k}}}={\frac {(\mathbf {v} \otimes \mathbf {w} )_{jk}}{(\mathbf {v} \otimes \mathbf {w} )_{ik}}}$$
rather than
$$
{\frac {v_{j}}{v_{i}}}={\frac {v_{j}w_{k}}{v_{i}w_{k}}}={\frac {(\mathbf {v} \otimes \mathbf {w} )_{jk}}{(\mathbf {v} \otimes \mathbf {w} )_{kj}}}  \;\;.
$$
Please correct me if I am wrong.

My question is beyond these typos. Guys from computer science often talk about things like "tensor space". I think they mean "tensor product", which is a finite-dimensional vector space from a finite number of vector spaces. Is "tensor space" a standard term in mathematics? Provided I want to refer to a subspace of a "tensor product", should I call it "tensor subspace" or something like "tensor sub-product"
What are the standard mathematical terms?

Are there mathematical books/articles ever talking about things like "tensor product by several modules"? Since the notion of modules generalizes the notion of vector space. I believe "tensor product by several modules", i.e., tensor product over a ring rather than a field makes sense.

Are there specialists interested to comment or give clues on reading materials? Thank you in advance.

Comment: For (1) I don't see a difference to the Wikipedia article in its current state. For (2) both Wikipedia and your suggestion are wrong, it should be $\frac{v_j}{v_i} = \frac{(\mathbf v\otimes\mathbf w)_{jk}}{(\mathbf v\otimes\mathbf w)_{ik}}$.

Comment: Of course you can form tensor products of modules over rings. Indeed, the [same Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product#Tensor_products_of_modules_over_a_ring) explains this.

Comment: Thanks, Christoph. For (2), you are right. I made a typo myself. My typo is corrected.  For (1), Wikipedia has typos on the subscripts. If you see more carefully, you see the difference.

Comment: You're right, the lengths $n$ and $m$ are obviously swapped. I don't see why you require clarification for that though, it's an obvious typo and there's nothing to discuss?

Comment: i would like to know standard math terms on things like "tensor space".